# Datagrid checkbox column select not working right

Tags: c#, select, datagrid, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I want to have a column with checkboxes that when ever the user clicks them, they select  their own row (hightlight it). I have come up with this code, with does not do the job, how can I fix it?

Is there a better way of doing this? (The row stays highlighter even after I "uncheck" the checkbox).

```
 private void dataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != -1) 
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == true)
                    dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = false;
                else if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == false)
                    dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CellMouseUp` will not work for selection with SPACE press.
If you don't have to do "real" selection, I'd change row background color on cell value change, it'd be much easier:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == true)
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        else if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == false)
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the logic in a `CellMouseUp` event handler as the `CellClick` event is occurring before the CheckBox state has been updated.

This along with using the [`EditedFormattedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.editedformattedvalue.aspx) property (which contains the current, formatted value of the cell) to retrieve the CheckBoxes current state.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.editedformattedvalue.aspx):

> The Value property is the actual data object contained by the cell,
>   whereas the FormattedValue is the formatted representation of this
>   object.
>
> It stores the  the current, formatted value of the cell, regardless of whether 
>   the cell is in edit mode and the value has not been committed.

Here is a working example.

```
void dataGrid_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell =
            dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        if (checkBoxCell != null)
        {
            dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(checkBoxCell.EditedFormattedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I want also the other checked rows to stay selected, how can I do that?